# How to create a new list outside the list itself

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

Is there any method can create the new list in this format in a loop?
Like:

```py
for i in list(**args):
   
    output1=[]
  
    output1.append("afadas")

# Then 
    output2=[]
   
    output2.append("aaaa")

# Then 
   
    output3=[]
   
    output3.append("dadas")
```

Since i do not know the number of arguments, so i want to create the new lists based on how many times this loop runs. Like: listh, h=2 => list2 instead of creating the list2 directly

Comment: Can you give as an example of input and output in a formatted way. Sounds like this might be a recursion problem.

Comment: Can you just make a list of lists?